# iPad: Can not move past first page of PDF

Tags: pdf, ipad, html-object

PDF's display in-line in my application.  They work nicely on a desktop or laptop.  On an iPad however, only the first page displays and there are no navigation bars so the user can not move beyond the first page.

I have tested both Chrome and Safari, with the same result.

Here's the code.  (It's part of a `vue.js` component.)

```
<object :data="rawCvLink" type="application/pdf" width="868px" height="800px">
    <p>There was a problem loading this CV.</p>
    <p>Otherwise, try loading the CV <a :href="cvDocumentLink" target="_blank">here</a></p>
</object>
```